# Select data based on multiple criteria using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, select

I am new to using Pandas. I want to select rows from a dataframe where multiple columns match in value. Along the lines of:

if column A equals column AB and column B equals column BC

then I want those values.

I haven't actually used an if statement, I read iteration was not good to use with pandas.

I've tried to find a solution, I'm not sure if it is my syntax or if its unhappy with different data types of the columns?

My code is a little long, so I'll provided just the line where I attempt the selection but I can post the entire code if that is helpful.

```
dfequal=dfMerged.loc[(dfMerged['MetCode']==dfMerged['GCD_METCODE']) & (dfMerged[dfMerged['Zone Code']==dfMerged['GCD_Senior_ZONE']]) & (dfMerged[dfMerged['Municipality Code']==dfMerged['GCD_CSDUID']])]
```

Edit*

The expected output would be a dataframe where only rows where the statement is true would exist.

This is the error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (84778,) (4462,)

This is my data table i'm pulling from

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Gdu.png)

```
    FileID,MetCode,Municipality Code,Zone 
Code,GCD_Senior_ZONE,GCD_METCODE,GCD_CSDUID
A100101,7175,1005018,303006,303006,7175,1005018
A100102,7175,1005018,303006,303006,7175,1005018
A100103,7175,1005018,303006,303006,7175,1005018
A100104,7280,1006009,202003,202003,7280,1006009
A100105,7300,1006017,202003,202003,7300,1006017
A100108,7300,1006017,202003,202003,7300,1006017
A100109,7300,1006017,202003,202003,7300,1006017
A100110,1640,1001485,101001,101001,1640,1001485
A100111,1640,1001517,101001,101001,1640,1001517
A100114,9000,1008011,202003,202003,0,1008011
A100115,9000,1001370,101002,101002,0,1001370
A100119,9000,1003034,202003,202003,0,1003034
```

Comment: it would be good if you included a small subset of your data so we could reproduce your desired behavior and what your expected output is. You don't need to include the entire code, but we have no way to be sure if we are right or wrong with the information you have provided as your column names are not even 'A', 'AB', 'B', 'BC'.

Comment: And what is exactly your problem? Did you get an error after running your code?

Comment: Can you create some simple dummy data and expected outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll simply need to add the conditions inside parenthesis inside your `.loc` and not repeat a DF filter inside the df filter:

First, creating a crude datasample, as you didn't provide one besides the image:

```
# creating the values, first one will be ID, then next 4 will be the values to compare
check_values = [
    [1, 5, 10, 20, 30],
    [2, 5, 11, 32, 11],
    [3, 10, 10, 20, 20],
    [4, 9, 9, 11, 11],
    [5, 11, 23, 41, 11]
]

# creating columns names
check_cols = ['id', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# making the DataFrame
dfcheck = pd.DataFrame(check_values, columns=check_cols)

# Setting the id column, just because
dfcheck.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

**The solution**, where you need to nest each condition inside parenthesis:

```
dfcheck.loc[(dfcheck['A'] == dfcheck['B']) & (dfcheck['C'] == dfcheck['D'])]
```

**EDIT: What you missed/did wrong?:**

Looking at your filter, you're adding unecessary dfMerged inside your parenthesis, your code broken in lines (delete everything inside "** CODE **"):

```
dfequal=
dfMerged.loc[(dfMerged['MetCode']==dfMerged['GCD_METCODE']) 
& (**dfMerged[**dfMerged['Zone Code']==dfMerged['GCD_Senior_ZONE']**]**) 
& (**dfMerged[**dfMerged['Municipality Code']==dfMerged['GCD_CSDUID']**]**)]
```

So you see, that you're searching inside a search that it's not needed? It should be:

```
dfequal=
dfMerged.loc[(dfMerged['MetCode']==dfMerged['GCD_METCODE']) 
& (dfMerged['Zone Code']==dfMerged['GCD_Senior_ZONE']) 
& (dfMerged['Municipality Code']==dfMerged['GCD_CSDUID'])]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it but my code already has parenthesis around each condition?

Comment: Welp, we both missed something. I for once missed that you did it, you that you're duplicating the `dfMerged` inside the parenthesis. I'll edit my answer so it's easier to explain. @aguay091, done, see my edited answer.